# When using 'df.groupby(column).apply()' get the groupby column within the 'apply' context?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, apply

I want to get the groupby column i.e. column that is supplied to `df.groupby` as a `by` argument (i.e. `df.groupby(by=column)`), within the `apply` context that comes after `groupby` (i.e. `df.groupby(by=column).apply(Here)`).

For example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal': ['Falcon', 'Falcon',
                              'Parrot', 'Parrot'],
                   'Max Speed': [380., 370., 24., 26.]})
df.groupby(['Animal']).apply(Here I want to know that groupby column is 'Animal')
```

```
df
   Animal  Max Speed
0  Falcon      380.0
1  Falcon      370.0
2  Parrot       24.0
3  Parrot       26.0
```

Of course, I can have one more line of code or simply by supplying the `groupby` column to the `apply` context separately (e.g. `.apply(lambda df_: some_function(df_,s='Animal'))` ), but I am curious to see if this can be done in a single line e.g. possibly using `pandas` function built for doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out a one-liner solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal': ['Falcon', 'Falcon',
                              'Parrot', 'Parrot'],
                   'Max Speed': [380., 370., 24., 26.]})
df.groupby(['Animal']).apply(lambda df_: df_.apply(lambda x: all(x==df_.name)).loc[lambda x: x].index.tolist())
```

returns groupby column within each groupby.apply context.

```
Animal
Falcon    [Animal]
Parrot    [Animal]
```

Since it is quite a long one-liner (uses 3 `lambda`s!), it is better to wrap it in a separate function, as shown below:

```
def get_groupby_column(df_): return df_.apply(lambda x: all(x==df_.name)).loc[lambda x: x].index.tolist()
df.groupby(['Animal']).apply(get_groupby_column)
```

Note of caution: this solution won't apply if other columns of the dataframe also contain the items from the groupby column e.g. if `Max Speed` column contained any of the items from the groupby column (i.e. `Animal`) there will be inaccurate results.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `grouper.names`:

```
>>> df.groupby('Animal').grouper.names
['Animal']
>>>
```

With `apply`:

```
grouped = df.groupby('Animal')
grouped.apply(lambda x: grouped.grouper.names)
```

Comment: The column name is not obtained within the `apply` though.

Comment: @Ramirez Check my edit

Comment: Yes, it does what I wanted to do. Thanks. I see that it is not a one-liner though.

Comment: @Ramirez It could be, but If I where you, I would for sure use my solution, I estimate that its ten times faster.